# Argument "by" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here is my reprodicible sample and code:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(Confidence=1:5, 
                  Type = ("Your confidence"),
                  Correct=sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)
)

dat %>%
  group_by(Confidence,Type) %>%
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct),
            se = (sd(Correct, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Confidence, y= Accuracy, color = Type, group = Type)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - se, ymax = Accuracy + se), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  labs(y= "YOU ARE RIGHT ___% OF THE TIME.", x = "WHEN YOU ARE ___ % CONFIDENT IN YOUR ANSWER...")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

When I run this i get this error:

```
Error in summarize(., Accuracy = mean(Correct), se = (sd(Correct, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n()))) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default
```

Has anyone seen this error before and know how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: How to make a reproducible example: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33807624/680068

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`summarize` is found in multiple packages and if we load many packages that have the `summarize` (depending on the order of loading the package) it could mask the function.  e.g. the error seems to be coming from `Hmisc::summarize`

```
> dat %>%
+   group_by(Confidence,Type) %>%
+   Hmisc::summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct),
+             se = (sd(Correct, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))%>%
+   ggplot(aes(x=Confidence, y= Accuracy, color = Type, group = Type)) +
+   geom_line() + 
+   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - se, ymax = Accuracy + se), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) + 
+   geom_point(size = 2)+ 
+   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
+   labs(y= "YOU ARE RIGHT ___% OF THE TIME.", x = "WHEN YOU ARE ___ % CONFIDENT IN YOUR ANSWER...")+
+   theme_minimal() + 
+   scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
Error in Hmisc::summarize(., Accuracy = mean(Correct), se = (sd(Correct,  : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default
```

If we change it to `dplyr::summarize`

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Confidence,Type) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct),
            se = (sd(Correct, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Confidence, y= Accuracy, color = Type, group = Type)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - se, ymax = Accuracy + se), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  labs(y= "YOU ARE RIGHT ___% OF THE TIME.", x = "WHEN YOU ARE ___ % CONFIDENT IN YOUR ANSWER...")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

-output

[image]