# Create a "Capitalize" function to work with vectors

Tags: r, string, sapply

This question comes after a brainstorm in this question [Capitalize the first letter of both words in a two word string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364783/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-both-words-in-a-two-word-string)

I would like to write a function that accepts vectors, which capitalizes every word in a sentence, and de-capitalizes the rest of the word. It is easier to only capitalize the first letter only:

```
CapitalizeFirstWord <- function(vector) {
  s <- sapply(sapply(vector, substring, 1, 1), toupper)
  t <- sapply(sapply(vector, substring, 2), tolower)
  binded <- cbind(s,t)
  apply(binded, 1, paste, collapse= "")
}
```

So that `CapitalizeFirstWord(c("heLlo", "ABC", "GooD daY"))` results in

```
 heLlo        ABC   GooD daY 
"Hello"      "Abc" "Good day"
```

( Wrote it with help with this question [Paste multiple columns together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568662/paste-multiple-columns-together-in-r) )

But I can't make it work so that every word in the sentence is capitalized.

This is my failed attempt:

```
CapitalizeEveryWord <- function(vector) {
  vectorS <- sapply(vector, strsplit, " ")
  s <- sapply(sapply(vectorS, substring, 1, 1), toupper)
  t <- sapply(sapply(vectorS, substring, 2), tolower)
  binded <- cbind(s,t)
  apply(binded, 1, paste, collapse= "")
}
```

So that `CapitalizeEveryWord(c("heLlo", "ABC", "GooD daY"))` results in

```
 heLlo                                 ABC                            GooD daY 
"Hello"                               "Abc" "c(\"G\", \"D\")c(\"ood\", \"ay\")"
```

I don't know how to change the `cbind()` or `paste()` functions' behaviour so that it is rearranged correctly.

I am doing this work because I have a really large data frame which has most of its strings capitalized.

The script should consume as less time as possible (because iterating with a `for()` loop, for every row and capitalizing only the first letter, is very slow, and I am having problems with it to work parallelized with `parLapply()`). That's why I used `*apply()` family of functions to create a new faster function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("\\b(.)", "\\U\\1", tolower(v1), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Hello"    "Abc"      "Good Day"
```

If it is to capitalize only first word

```
sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", tolower(v1), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Hello"    "Abc"      "Good day"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("heLlo", "ABC", "GooD daY")
```

Comment: Sorry for explaining me bad. I want also to de-capitalize the rest of the words. I've edited my question also to reflect this. I want capitalization in every word, but not in the rest of the word. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Both answers are correct, but I've tested that this way is a bit faster (in processing time) than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in function for this exact use-case from `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)

v1 <- c("heLlo", "ABC", "GooD daY")
stri_trans_totitle(v1)

## [1] "Hello"    "Abc"      "Good Day"
```