# Capitalize a column of characters

Tags: r, string, dataframe, character, capitalize

I have a dataframe where one of the columns shows the names of some counties in lowercase, sometimes with double spaces. For example:

```
df$counties
# [1] "san diego county"  "napa   county"  "san   francisco county"
```

I need to capitalize each of the words and eliminate any multiple spaces. That is, I aim for this result:

```
df$counties
# [1]"San Diego County"  "Napa County"  "San Francisco County"
```

Would appreciate any kind advice.

Comment: see, in particular, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365349/1017276

Comment: Thank you, @Benjamin & Cath. Indeed this was a duplicate question and now I have my answer. Cheers!