# Convert uppercase Letter addresses to lower case in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has many addresses but they are all in uppercase and I want them to be in lower case but keeping the first letter of the word as an upper case.

I use the function `lowercase` but the whole word turns lower case

in this case

```
tolower("231 MATTIE'S WAY")
[1] "231 mattie's way"
```

but I need it like

```
"231 Matties's Way"
```

Any help on how I could do that?

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364905/5977215) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527665/5977215)?

Comment: The examples in the documentation for `tolower` contain a simple title case function. There is also such a function in the **stringr** package, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those questions out, I got the answer from there:)