# How to convert a single string, with word separated by commas, into multiple strings?

Tags: r

I'm building a shiny app and in my app the user gives as input a string such as the following:

```
cats,dogs,birds,cows
```

So, several words separated by commas, with no spaces. 
The thing is I want to capitalize each of those words and I can only do it by making R see the string as a group of strings, so the result of the capitalization should be:

```
Cats,Dogs,Birds,Cows
```

I really don't know how to do this, and the problem is that my string isn't even a vector because it is coded as such:

```
unlist(strsplit(input, ",")))
```

I'm sorry if this was confusing and thank in advance for any answer

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You may want to check a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364783/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-both-words-in-a-two-word-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility could be:

```
x <- c("cats,dogs,birds,cows", "cats,dogs,birds")
sapply(strsplit(x, ",", fixed = TRUE), 
       function(x) paste0(tools::toTitleCase(x), collapse = ","))

[1] "Cats,Dogs,Birds,Cows" "Cats,Dogs,Birds"
```

And there is also a handy library called `snakecase`:

```
to_upper_camel_case(x, sep_out = ",")

[1] "Cats,Dogs,Birds,Cows" "Cats,Dogs,Birds"
```