# Capitalise every word of a sentence except the very first letter

Tags: r, string

I want to `capitalise` every word of a sentence except the very first letter. There is a similar discussion here - [Capitalize the first letter of both words in a two word string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364783/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-both-words-in-a-two-word-string)

So the function can be used as -

```
name <- c("zip code", "state", "final count")
simpleCap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),
      sep="", collapse=" ")
}
sapply(name, simpleCap)
```

But it also capitalise the first letter as well. I want something like `"zip Code"` instead `"Zip Code"`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some basic regex:

```
name <- c("zip code", "state", "final count")
gsub("\\s([a-z])", " \\U\\1", name, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "zip Code"     "state"        "final Count"
```

To allow for non-ascii letters:

```
name <- c("zip code", "state", "final count", "uribe álvaro")
gsub("\\s(\\p{L})", " \\U\\1", name, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "zip Code"     "state"        "final Count"  "uribe Álvaro"
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the second solution in that link using `toTitleCase`. You can use regex to make the first character lower-case.

```
simpleCap <- function(x) {
  sub('(.)', '\\L\\1', tools::toTitleCase(x), perl = TRUE)
}

simpleCap('Zip Code')
#[1] "zip Code"
simpleCap('this text')
#[1] "this Text"
simpleCap(name)
#[1] "zip Code"    "state"       "final Count"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with slight modification of the `strsplit` approach:

```
capExceptFirst <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  
  paste(
    tolower(s[1]),
    paste(toupper(substring(s[-1], 1,1)), substring(s[-1], 2),
        sep="", collapse=" "),
    collapse = " "
  )
}

sapply(name, capExceptFirst)
```

Output:

```
     zip code         state   final count 
   "zip Code"      "state " "final Count"
```